# DATABASE optimization insert and search

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I was having an argument with a friend of mine. Suppose we have a db table with a userid and some other fields. This table might have a lot of rows. Let's suppose also that by design we limit the records for each userid in the table to about 50.My friend suggested that if I under every row for each userid one after another the lookup would be faster e.g

```
userid otherfield
1      .........
1      .........
.....until 50...
2       ........
```

etc. So when a user id 1 is created I pre-popopulate the 50 table's rows to with null values...etc. The idea is that if I know the amount of rows and find the first row with userid =1 I just have to look the next 49 an voila I don't have to search the whole table. Is this correct?can this be done without indexing? Is the pre-population an expensive process?Is there a performance difference if I just inserted in old fashioned way like

```
1 ........
2 ........
2 ........
1 ........
```

etc?

Comment: Hard to understand exactly what you are proposing, but it sounds like a bad idea from what I can glean. Don't try to outsmart MySQL with an overly complex solution like this. Only pain will come from it. Can you show your table structure and proposed query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer a performance question like this, you should run performance tests on the different configurations.

But, let me make a few points.

First, although you might know that the records for a given id are located next to each other, the database does not know this.  So, if you are searching for one user -- without an index -- then the engine needs to search through all the records (unless you have a `limit` clause in the query).

Second, if the data is fixed length (numeric and dates), the populating it with values after populating it with `NULL` values will occupy the same space on the page.  But, if the data is variable length, then a given page will be filled with empty records.  When you modify the records with real values, you will get page split.

What you are trying to do is to outsmart the database engine.  This isn't necessary, because MySQL provides indexes, which provide almost all the benefits that you are describing.

Now, having said that, there *is* some performance benefit from having all the records for a user being co-located.  If a user has 50 records, then reading the records with an index would typically require loading 50 pages into memory.  If the records are co-located, then only one or two records would need to be read.  Typically, this would be a very small performance gain, because most frequently accessed tables fit into memory.  There might be some circumstances where the performance gain is worth it.

Comment: What if I wanted to prepopulate 1000 rows.would there be gain in performance when searching; By accessed table u mean that when u search in a db the whole table would be loaded in memory correct?

Comment: @Apostolos . . . 1000 rows would have a minimal effect on performance because all the data would readily fit in memory.  It is not worth even trying.